# Let $p,q$ be primes such that $p+q^2$ is a perfect square. Show that $p^2+q^n$ is not a perfect square for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $p,q$ be primes such that $p+q^2$ is a perfect square. Show that $p^2+q^n$ is not a perfect square for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

By the hypothesis we know that $p+q^2 = a^2$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus $$p=q^2-a^2=(a+q)(a-q)$$ and since $p$ is a prime $a+q=1,a-q=p$ or $a+q=p,a-q=1$. We can disregard the first case since if $a<0$, then $a-q$ cannot equal $p$ and if $a>0$, then $a+q>1$.

So $a+q=p$ and $a-q=1$. The second equation gives $a=1+q$ and plugging this in to the equation for $p$ above gives $$p=(1+q+q)(1+q-q)=1+2q.$$

Now plugging this into $p^2+q^n$ gives $$(1+2q)^2+q^n=1+4q+4q^2+q^n.$$

If we now assume that $p^2+q^n$ is a perfect square i.e. $p^2+q^n=b^2$ this gives that $$q^n=(b+p)(b-p)=b^2-4q^2-4q-1 \equiv b^2-1\equiv b^2+3 \pmod 4$$

and since $b^2$ is a square $b^2 \equiv 0,1 \pmod 4$ gives that $$q^n\equiv 0,3 \pmod 4.$$ Can I derive a contradiction from here at all?

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24p%2Bq%5E2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24p%5E2%2Bq%5En%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprimes%2C%20OR%20content%3Aperfect%20square&p=1), there's the duplicate (but with no answer) [Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are two prime numbers such that $p+q^2$ is a perfect square.](/q/3665322), as well as the AoPS threads [Perfect square, hard problem!](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2354900p19118310) and [Prime powers](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1832879p12277912).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've made a good start by determining that $p=2q+1$. From here it follows that if
$$p^2+q^n=b^2,$$
for some integer $b$, then also
$$q^n=b^2-p^2=(b+p)(b-p).$$
Then $b+p=q^u$ and $b-p=q^v$ for some integers $u$ and $v$ with $u+v=n$. Clearly $u>v$ because $p>0$, and so
$$2p=(b+p)-(b-p)=q^u-q^v=q^v(q^{u-v}-1).\tag{1}$$
This means that $q^v$ divides $2p$, so either $v=1$ and $q\in\{2,p\}$, or $v=0$. None are possible:

For $v=1$, clearly $q=p$ is impossible as we already saw that $p=2q+1$. For $q=2$ we find that $p=5$ but then equation $(1)$ becomes
$$10=2^1(2^{u-1}-1),$$
which does not have any integral solution. Finally, for $v=0$ we get
$$q^u-1=q^v(q^{u-v}-1)=2p=2(2q+1)=4q+2.$$
This implies $q^u-4q-3=0$ and so $q$ divides $3$, and again we see that this does not have any integral solution. This shows that $p^2+q^n$ is never a perfect square.